# Yii : Add limits , for can't get access to another page with change URL

Tags: php, yii

in my index my users only can see their text's
but if users change url for exmaple:
/index.php/text/22
to 
/index.php/text/21

their can access to another text  users

this is my controller :

```
    <?php

class TextController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Text;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Text']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Text'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Text']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Text'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {

            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text',array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id',
            'params' => array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->User->id),)));


            $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

    ));




//      $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Text');
//      $this->render('index',array(
//          'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
//      ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Text('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Text']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Text'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return Text the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Text::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param Text $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='text-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

in the index user can only their notes but  i want with change url their can't access to another notes of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your text model, i found you have the column named "user_id", if "user_id" means create the text record by someone who login into your system, we can write the code like below to prevent other users update data that they not owned:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    //check user_id
    if ($model->user_id !== Yii::app()->user->id)
    {
        echo "YOU SHALL NOT PASS !";
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Text']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Text'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You're a genius, you know what I want and you could fix it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Make a relation (pk + fk), eg, 22 or 21 fk and logged in user's id is pk. if 22 or 21 is related with logged in user's id then show it else give alert.

Comment: in the actionindex(){}  i could set limited access very easily
I feel it should be very easy in Yii